# Insert equation in google sheet using python and the google sheet API

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

`newRow = ["some_data", "some_data", "=MULTIPLY(A1;BA)"]`

When I'm trying this, in my google sheet, the cell in filled by : `'=MULTIPLY(O33;M33)` as a string. How can I make my equation usable ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "" in your code will do the trick